# how to CNAME subdomain url to url subfolder on Amazon AWS

Tags: cname, amazon-route53

in Godaddy or Cloudflare I can in DNS setup a subdomain for pointing to url/subfolder. When I do it in Amazon Route 53 it doesn't work.

Basically what I need is to make a kind of CNAME:
having a subdomain url point it to another domain url with subfolder without change subdomain url.

is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a URL redirection service that is a combination of two services, HTTP (the service doing the redirect) and DNS (the service resolving the dns record to an IP address).  You can accomplish this using Route 53 (DNS) and and Amazon S3 Web Sites (HTTP).

1. Create an S3 bucket matches the subdomain you want to redirect (redirect.example.com)
2. Enable "Redirect All requests to another host name" under your S3 bucket settings and set the url you want to redirect to.
3. In Route 53, create the record, redirect.example.com, and alias it to your S3 bucket.

Additional information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-switch-to-route53-as-dnsprovider

Comment: I did it but what I needed is to "mask" the pointed domain/subdirectory with the subdomain.

Comment: To do that, you would have to setup a static page for step 2 that loads the target page in an iframe.